# How to test for an empty structure being returned via a Solidity function()?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, solidity

Here is a sample Solidity contract where I have a function which returns an empty struct.

I want to test from a function inside the contract for the empty struct, but I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax ...

```
contract MyNFTShop is ERC721 {

    struct NFTCardAttributes {
        uint256 cardIndex;
        string name;
        string imageURI;
    }

    NFTCardAttributes[] defaultCards;

    constructor(
        string[] memory cardNames,
        string[] memory cardImageURIs,
    ) ERC721("NFT", "NFTC") {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i += 1) {
            defaultCards.push(
                NFTCardAttributes({
                    cardIndex: i,
                    name: cardNames[i],
                    imageURI: cardImageURIs[i],
                })
            );

            NFTCardAttributes memory c = defaultCards[i];
        }

    }


    function checkIfUserHasNFTCard() public view returns (NFTCardAttributes memory) {
        uint256 userNFTCardNftTokenId = nftCardHolders[msg.sender];
        if(userNFTCardNftTokenId > 0 ) {
            return nftCardHolderAttributes[userNFTCardNftTokenId];
        } else {
            NFTCardAttributes memory emptyStruct;
            return emptyStruct;
        }
    }


    function do_something() public () {
        if (getAllDefaultCards() == EMPTY) { <---- NEED HELP HERE
            // sendMoney to whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Help with this Solidity function. I know it returns (0,0,0) when called from brownie/python but I don't know how to test for it. [ the struct returned is indeed empty aka (0,0,0) using Solidity. ]

```
function do_something() public () {
    if (getAllDefaultCards() == EMPTY) { <---- NEED HELP HERE
        // sendMoney to whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “test from a function”? What are you expecting to code?

Comment: I updated the question. I am basically not sure how to compare the returned value of the empty struct (0,0,0).  if (getAllDefaultCards() == (0,0,0) ) gives compilation errors

Answer (score 0):

A WORKAROUND

I basically split the function into two separate functions to get the desired affect:

```
function checkIfUserHasNFTCard() public view returns (bool)
function getUserHasNFTCard() public view returns (NFTCardAttributes)
```

Although, the primary question still stands and will update once I figure out the answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).